# Can't load a values from $wpdb

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have in wordpress db these values:

[image]

```
                    global $wpdb;

                    $sql = "SELECT `post_excerpt` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE (`wp_posts`.`post_excerpt` LIKE 'fasad_%') ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`post_excerpt` ASC";
                    $materials = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                    foreach ($materials as $material) {

                        $fasads_kitchen = $material->post_excerpt;
                        echo $fasads_kitchen;                              
                    }
```

It's ok. The values are shown. But after that I need to execute a foreach function like this:

```
                     foreach ($fasads_kitchen as $fasad_arg) {                            
                        // an error is here
                        if( have_rows($fasad_arg) ): ?>
                               while ( have_rows($fasad_arg) ) : the_row();
                               //something
                    }
```

But have an error:  **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**.
I tried to use

```
foreach ((array)$fasads_kitchen as $fasad_arg) {
```

but the debugger says that it's not an array.

Is it a string variable or what? How to fix that?

If I'm using

```
$fasads_kitchen = array('fasad_plastic','fasad_mdf') {}
```

it's working, but I need to load these values from wpdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a string when you use

```
$fasads_kitchen = $material->post_excerpt;
```

`$fasads_kitchen` needs to be an array:

```
$fasads_kitchen = array();    
foreach ($materials as $material) {
    array_push($fasads_kitchen, $material->post_excerpt); 
    // or use one of the many ways to add to an array                         
}
```

Then you can loop through `$fasads_kitchen`

Comment: Yes, I didn't know how to convert a string to array. Thank you so much.